# Ubuntu 18.04 does not maximize => 3840x2160 resolution

Tags: ubuntu, screen-resolution, ubuntu-18.04, wayland

Been trying to get 3840x2160 with my dual monitors (4k UHD Dell 27") through Displayports with lightning adapter but couldn't sort it out.

**Machine** => Dell XPS 13"
**Kernel version**=> 4.15.0.47

Sometimes I can get it to work when i keep my laptop lid open, but most of the time I don't see an option to get 3840x2160 resolution for the both of monitors. It is like an intermittent issue.

Only resolution that I'm currently using and stable is 2048x1280 16:10, but this is not ideal as the text/fonts are quite blurry.

Any tips or suggestions? Thank you in advance!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/ or https://superuser.com/ are better forums for this question.  StackOverflow is meant for programming questions while AskUbuntu and SuperUser cover more general questions that include hardware.

Comment: Thanks mate appreciate it